# How to use data frame as an element in list?

Tags: r

I tried to assign a data frame as an element to a list, but after the assignment I found that the data frame has been changed to a list with values from the first column of the data frame.

For example the following code :

```
dfm <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=3:4)
print(dfm)
l <- list()
l['Key'] <- dfm
print(l)
```

gives the output:

```
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
$Key
[1] 1 2
```

Is there a way to keep the data frame the way it is in a list ?

Comment: What do you mean "keep the data frame the way it is"?  The data frame is an element of `l`.

Comment: @JackManey. You can see that the element in the list has been changed to a vector of (1,2), not the data frame I assigned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would benefit you to pay attention to the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In l["Key"] <- dfm :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

You want to use `[[` instead of `[` (read `?Extract` to understand why):

```
l[['Key']] <- dfm
```